# Why the java code for inpainting when used in android gives error in calculate gradient method

Tags: java, android, image-processing, gradient

Here is the code I am working on. I have used a java code on android studio platform to inapint an image where inpaint means removing the selected region in an image without affecting the background. I have edited other lines and made them error free. Only one error still exists which is in the Calculategradient method and even in the GradientCalculator datatype gc in the beginning. Please help.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;

/*     */ import java.io.PrintStream;
/*     */ import java.util.Vector;
/*     */ 
/*     */ public class ImageInpaint
/*     */ {
/*     */   Bitmap origImg;
/*     */   Bitmap fillImg;
/*     */   Bitmap img;
/*     */   int iw;
/*     */   int ih;
/*     */   int[] pixels;
/*     */   int[][] pixelmap;
/*     */   int[][] fillPixelmap;
/*     */   int[][] sourceRegion;
/*     */   int[][] initialSourceRegion;
/*     */   double[][] fillRegion;
/*     */   double[][] gradientX;
/*     */   double[][] gradientY;
/*     */   double[][] confidence;
/*     */   double[][] data;
/*  57 */   double omega = 0.7D;
/*  58 */   double Alpha = 0.2D;
/*  59 */   double Beta = 0.8D;
/*     */   int maxX;
/*     */   int maxY;
/*     */   int minX;
/*     */   int minY;
/*  64 */   int continuousCol = 0;
/*  65 */   int continuousRow = 0;
/*     */   GradientCalculator gc;
/*  67 */   public Boolean halt = Boolean.valueOf(false);
/*  68 */   public Boolean completed = Boolean.valueOf(false);
/*  69 */   final int diamX = 50;
/*  70 */   final int diamY = 30;
/*     */   private int pixelPosX;
/*     */   private int pixelPosY;
/*  73 */   int i,w = 3;
/*  74 */   double[][] con = { { 1.0D, 1.0D, 1.0D }, { 1.0D, -8.0D, 1.0D }, { 1.0D, 1.0D, 1.0D } };

/*     */   
/*     */   public void init(Bitmap a_origImg, Bitmap a_fillImg, Boolean quickInpaint)
/*     */   {
/*  93 */     this.halt = Boolean.valueOf(false);
/*     */
/* 145 */     initialize_confidence_term();
/* 146 */     initialize_data_term();
/*     */     
/* 148 */     this.fillRegion = new double[this.ih][this.iw];
/* 149 */     this.sourceRegion = new int[this.ih][this.iw];
/* 150 */     this.initialSourceRegion = new int[this.ih][this.iw];
/*     */     
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 155 */     this.minX = this.iw;
/* 156 */     this.minY = this.ih;
/* 157 */     this.maxX = (this.maxY = 0);
/*     */     
/*     */ 
/* 160 */     this.continuousRow = (this.continuousCol = 0);
/* 161 */     for (int i = 0; i < this.ih; i++)
/*     */     {
/* 162 */       int countrow = 0;
/* 163 */       for (int j = 0; j < this.iw; j++)
/*     */       {
/* 164 */         int pixel = this.fillPixelmap[i][j];
/* 165 */         int r = 0xFF & pixel >> 16;
/* 166 */         int g = 0xFF & pixel >> 8;
/* 167 */         int b = 0xFF & pixel;
/* 172 */         if ((r == 0) && (g == 255) && (b == 0))
/*     */         {
/* 173 */           countrow++;
/* 174 */           this.fillRegion[i][j] = 1.0D;
/* 175 */           this.sourceRegion[i][j] = 0;
/* 176 */           this.initialSourceRegion[i][j] = 0;
/* 177 */           if (j < this.minX) {
/* 178 */             this.minX = j;
/*     */           }
/* 180 */           if (i < this.minY) {
/* 181 */             this.minY = i;
/*     */           }
/* 183 */           if (j > this.maxX) {
/* 184 */             this.maxX = j;
/*     */           }
/* 186 */           if (i > this.maxY) {
/* 187 */             this.maxY = i;
/*     */           }
/*     */         }
/*     */         else
/*     */         {
/* 190 */           if (countrow > this.continuousRow) {
/* 191 */             this.continuousRow = countrow;
/*     */           }
/* 193 */           countrow = 0;
/* 194 */           this.fillRegion[i][j] = 0.0D;
/* 195 */           this.sourceRegion[i][j] = 1;
/* 196 */           this.initialSourceRegion[i][j] = 1;
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 201 */     for (int i = 0; i < this.iw; i++)
/*     */     {
/* 202 */       int countcol = 0;
/* 203 */       for (int j = 0; j < this.ih; j++)
/*     */       {
/* 204 */         int pixel = this.fillPixelmap[j][i];
/* 205 */         int r = 0xFF & pixel >> 16;
/* 206 */         int g = 0xFF & pixel >> 8;
/* 207 */         int b = 0xFF & pixel;
/* 211 */         if ((r == 0) && (g == 255) && (b == 0))
/*     */         {
/* 212 */           countcol++;
/*     */         }
/*     */         else
/*     */         {
/* 214 */           if (countcol > this.continuousCol) {
/* 215 */             this.continuousCol = countcol;
/*     */           }
/* 217 */           countcol = 0;
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 225 */     Boolean flag = Boolean.valueOf(true);
/*     */     
/* 227 */     double[][] temp = new double[this.ih][this.iw];
/* 228 */     double[][] sourceGradX = new double[this.ih][this.iw];
/* 229 */     double[][] sourceGradY = new double[this.ih][this.iw];
/*     */     
/* 231 */     Vector dR = new Vector();
/* 232 */     Vector Nx = new Vector();
/* 233 */     Vector Ny = new Vector();
/* 239 */     while (flag.booleanValue())
/*     */     {
/* 244 */       temp = conv2(this.fillRegion, this.con);
/*     */       
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 249 */       this.gc.calculateGradient(this.sourceRegion, this.ih, this.iw);
/* 250 */       sourceGradX = this.gc.gradientX;
/* 251 */       sourceGradY = this.gc.gradientY;
/*     */       
/* 253 */       dR.clear();
/* 254 */       Nx.clear();
/* 255 */       Ny.clear();
/* 260 */       for (i = 0; i < temp[0].length; i++) {
/* 261 */         for (int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
/* 262 */           if (temp[j][i] > 0.0D)
/*     */           {
/* 263 */             dR.add(Integer.valueOf(i * temp.length + j));
/* 264 */             Nx.add(Double.valueOf(sourceGradX[j][i]));
/* 265 */             Ny.add(Double.valueOf(sourceGradY[j][i]));
/*     */           }
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/* 270 */       double[][] N = normr(Nx, Ny);
/*     */       
/* 272 */       Vector q = new Vector();
/* 273 */       double count = 0.0D;
/* 278 */       for (int i = 0; i < dR.size(); i++)
/*     */       {
/* 279 */         int[][] Hp = getpatch(this.pixelmap, ((Integer)dR.get(i)).intValue());
/* 280 */         for (int j = 0; j < Hp.length; j++) {
/* 281 */           for (int k = 0; k < Hp[0].length; k++)
/*     */           {
/* 282 */             int col = Hp[j][k] / this.ih;
/* 283 */             int row = Hp[j][k] % this.ih;
/* 284 */             if (this.fillRegion[row][col] == 0.0D)
/*     */             {
/* 285 */               count += this.confidence[row][col];
/* 286 */               q.add(Integer.valueOf(Hp[j][k]));
/*     */             }
/*     */           }
/*     */         }
/* 291 */         int col = ((Integer)dR.get(i)).intValue() / this.ih;
/* 292 */         int row = ((Integer)dR.get(i)).intValue() % this.ih;
/* 293 */         this.confidence[row][col] = (count / (Hp.length * Hp[0].length));
/* 294 */         count = 0.0D;
/*     */       }
/* 297 */       double maxPriority = 0.0D;
/* 298 */       int maxPriorityIndex = -1;
/* 303 */       for (int i = 0; i < dR.size(); i++)
/*     */       {
/* 304 */         int col = ((Integer)dR.get(i)).intValue() / this.ih;
/* 305 */         int row = ((Integer)dR.get(i)).intValue() % this.ih;
/*     */         
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 310 */         this.data[row][col] = (Math.abs(this.gradientX[row][col] * N[i][0] + this.gradientY[row][col] * N[i][1]) + 0.001D);
/*     */         
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 315 */         double Rcp = (1.0D - this.omega) * this.confidence[row][col] + this.omega;
/*     */         
/* 317 */         double tempPriority = this.Alpha * Rcp + this.Beta * this.data[row][col];
/* 322 */         if (tempPriority >= maxPriority)
/*     */         {
/* 323 */           maxPriority = tempPriority;
/* 324 */           maxPriorityIndex = i;
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/* 328 */       if (maxPriorityIndex == -1) {
/*     */         break;
/*     */       }
/* 336 */       int[][] Hp = getpatch(this.pixelmap, ((Integer)dR.get(maxPriorityIndex)).intValue());
/* 337 */       double[][] toFill = new double[Hp.length][Hp[0].length];
/* 338 */       double[][] toFillTrans = new double[Hp[0].length][Hp.length];
/* 343 */       for (int i = 0; i < Hp.length; i++) {
/* 344 */         for (int j = 0; j < Hp[0].length; j++)
/*     */         {
/* 345 */           int col = Hp[i][j] / this.ih;
/* 346 */           int row = Hp[i][j] % this.ih;
/* 347 */           toFill[i][j] = this.fillRegion[row][col];
/* 348 */           toFillTrans[j][i] = this.fillRegion[row][col];
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/* 352 */       this.pixelPosX = (((Integer)dR.get(maxPriorityIndex)).intValue() / this.ih);
/* 353 */       this.pixelPosY = (((Integer)dR.get(maxPriorityIndex)).intValue() % this.ih);
/*     */       
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 358 */       int[] best = bestExemplar(Hp, toFillTrans, this.initialSourceRegion, quickInpaint);
/*     */       
/* 360 */       int nRows = best[3] - best[2] + 1;
/* 361 */       int nCols = best[1] - best[0] + 1;
/*     */       
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 366 */       int[][] X = new int[nRows][nCols];
/* 367 */       int[][] Y = new int[nRows][nCols];
/* 368 */       int[][] Hq = new int[nRows][nCols];
/* 369 */       for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
/* 370 */         for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++)
/*     */         {
/* 371 */           X[i][j] = (best[0] + j);
/* 372 */           Y[i][j] = (best[2] + i);
/* 373 */           X[i][j] += Y[i][j] * this.ih;
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/* 377 */       int p = ((Integer)dR.get(maxPriorityIndex)).intValue();
/* 382 */       for (int i = 0; i < toFill.length; i++) {
/* 383 */         for (int j = 0; j < toFill[0].length; j++) {
/* 384 */           if (toFill[i][j] != 0.0D)
/*     */           {
/* 385 */             toFill[i][j] = 1.0D;
/* 386 */             int col = Hp[i][j] / this.ih;
/* 387 */             int row = Hp[i][j] % this.ih;
/*     */             
/* 389 */             int col1 = Hq[i][j] / this.ih;
/* 390 */             int row1 = Hq[i][j] % this.ih;
/*     */             
/* 392 */             this.fillRegion[row][col] = 0.0D;
/* 393 */             this.sourceRegion[row][col] = 1;
/*     */             
/*     */ 
/* 396 */             this.confidence[row][col] = this.confidence[(p % this.ih)][(p / this.ih)];
/* 397 */             this.gradientX[row][col] = this.gradientX[row1][col1];
/* 398 */             this.gradientY[row][col] = this.gradientY[row1][col1];
/* 399 */             this.pixelmap[row][col] = this.pixelmap[row1][col1];
/*     */             
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 404 */             int[] color = new int[3];
/* 405 */             color[0] = (0xFF & this.pixelmap[row1][col1] >> 16);
/* 406 */             color[1] = (0xFF & this.pixelmap[row1][col1] >> 8);
/* 407 */             color[2] = (0xFF & this.pixelmap[row1][col1]);
                      int rgb= Color.rgb(color[0],color[1],color[2]);
/* 408 */             this.origImg.setPixel(col, row, rgb);
/*     */           }
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/* 413 */       if (this.halt.booleanValue()) {
/*     */         break;
/*     */       }
/* 415 */       Thread.yield();
/*     */       
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 420 */       flag = Boolean.valueOf(false);
/* 421 */       for (int i = 0; i < this.fillRegion.length; i++)
/*     */       {
/* 422 */         for (int j = 0; j < this.fillRegion[0].length; j++) {
/* 423 */           if (this.fillRegion[i][j] == 1.0D)
/*     */           {
/* 424 */             flag = Boolean.valueOf(true);
/* 425 */             break;
/*     */           }
/*     */         }
/* 428 */         if (flag.booleanValue()) {
/*     */           break;
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/* 431 */       if (this.halt.booleanValue()) {
/*     */         break;
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 437 */     this.gc = null;
/* 438 */     if (!this.halt.booleanValue()) {
/* 439 */       this.completed = Boolean.valueOf(true);
/*     */     } else {
/* 441 */       this.completed = Boolean.valueOf(false);
/*     */     }
/* 443 */     this.origImg.updateStats(this.origImg);
/* 444 */     Thread.yield();
/*     */   }
/*     */   
/*     */   void initialize_confidence_term()
/*     */   {
/* 452 */     this.confidence = new double[this.ih][this.iw];
/* 453 */     for (int i = 0; i < this.ih; i++) {
/* 454 */       for (int j = 0; j < this.iw; j++)
/*     */       {
/* 455 */         int p = this.pixelmap[i][j];
/* 456 */         int r = 0xFF & p >> 16;
/* 457 */         int g = 0xFF & p >> 8;
/* 458 */         int b = 0xFF & p;
/* 459 */         if ((r == 0) && (g == 255) && (b == 0)) {
/* 460 */           this.confidence[i][j] = 0.0D;
/*     */         } else {
/* 462 */           this.confidence[i][j] = 1.0D;
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/*     */   }
/*     */   
/*     */   void initialize_data_term()
/*     */   {
/* 473 */     this.data = new double[this.ih][this.iw];
/* 474 */     for (int i = 0; i < this.ih; i++) {
/* 475 */       for (int j = 0; j < this.iw; j++) {
/* 476 */         this.data[i][j] = -0.1D;
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/*     */   }
/*     */   
/*     */   double[][] conv2(double[][] a, double[][] b)
/*     */   {
/* 489 */     int ra = a.length;
/* 490 */     int ca = a[0].length;
/* 491 */     int rb = b.length;
/* 492 */     int cb = b[0].length;
/*     */     
/*     */ 
/* 495 */     double[][] c = new double[ra + rb - 1][ca + cb - 1];
/* 496 */     for (int i = 0; i < rb; i++) {
/* 497 */       for (int j = 0; j < cb; j++)
/*     */       {
/* 498 */         int r1 = i;
/* 499 */         int r2 = r1 + ra - 1;
/* 500 */         int c1 = j;
/* 501 */         int c2 = c1 + ca - 1;
/* 502 */         for (int k = r1; k < r2; k++) {
/* 503 */           for (int l = c1; l < c2; l++) {
/* 504 */             c[k][l] += b[i][j] * a[(k - r1 + 1)][(l - c1 + 1)];
/*     */           }
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 510 */     double[][] out = new double[ra][ca];
/*     */     
/* 512 */     int r1 = rb / 2;
/* 513 */     int r2 = r1 + ra - 1;
/* 514 */     int c1 = cb / 2;
/* 515 */     int c2 = c1 + ca - 1;
/* 516 */     for (int i = r1; i < r2; i++) {
/* 517 */       for (int j = c1; j < c2; j++) {
/* 518 */         out[(i - r1 + 1)][(j - c1 + 1)] = c[i][j];
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 521 */     return out;
/*     */   }
/*     */   
/*     */   double[][] normr(Vector X, Vector Y)
/*     */   {
/* 533 */     double[][] normalized = new double[X.size()][2];
/* 534 */     for (int i = 0; i < X.size(); i++)
/*     */     {
/* 535 */       double temp1 = ((Double)X.get(i)).doubleValue();
/* 536 */       double temp2 = ((Double)Y.get(i)).doubleValue();
/*     */       
/* 538 */       temp1 *= temp1;
/* 539 */       temp2 *= temp2;
/*     */       double temp3;
/* 543 */       if (temp1 + temp2 == 0.0D)
/*     */       {
/* 544 */         temp3 = 0.0D;
/*     */       }
/*     */       else
/*     */       {
/* 546 */         temp3 = 1.0D / (temp1 + temp2);
/* 547 */         temp3 = Math.sqrt(temp3);
/*     */       }
/* 550 */       normalized[i][0] = (temp3 * ((Double)X.get(i)).doubleValue());
/* 551 */       normalized[i][1] = (temp3 * ((Double)Y.get(i)).doubleValue());
/*     */     }
/* 554 */     return normalized;
/*     */   }
/*     */   
/*     */   int[][] getpatch(int[][] pixelmap, int p)
/*     */   {
/* 570 */     p -= 1;
/* 571 */     int y = p / this.ih;
/* 572 */     p %= this.ih;
/* 573 */     int x = p + 1;
/*     */     
/* 575 */     int temp1 = Math.max(x - this.w, 0);
/* 576 */     int temp2 = Math.min(x + this.w, this.ih - 1);
/* 577 */     int temp3 = Math.max(y - this.w, 0);
/* 578 */     int temp4 = Math.min(y + this.w, this.iw - 1);
/*     */     
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 582 */     int[][] N = new int[temp4 - temp3 + 1][temp2 - temp1 + 1];
/* 584 */     for (int i = 0; i < temp4 - temp3 + 1; i++) {
/* 585 */       for (int j = 0; j < temp2 - temp1 + 1; j++) {
/* 588 */         N[i][j] = (temp1 + j + (temp3 + i) * this.ih);
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 591 */     return N;
/*     */   }
/*     */   
/*     */   int[] bestExemplar(int[][] Hp, double[][] toFill, int[][] sourceRegion, Boolean quickInpaint)
/*     */   {
/* 606 */     int[][] Ip = new int[toFill.length][toFill[0].length];
/* 607 */     for (int i = 0; i < toFill[0].length; i++) {
/* 608 */       for (int j = 0; j < toFill.length; j++)
/*     */       {
/* 609 */         int col = Hp[i][j] / this.ih;
/* 610 */         int row = Hp[i][j] % this.ih;
/* 611 */         Ip[j][i] = this.pixelmap[row][col];
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 615 */     int[][] rIp = new int[Ip.length][Ip[0].length];
/* 616 */     int[][] gIp = new int[Ip.length][Ip[0].length];
/* 617 */     int[][] bIp = new int[Ip.length][Ip[0].length];
/* 619 */     for (int i = 0; i < Ip.length; i++) {
/* 620 */       for (int j = 0; j < Ip[0].length; j++)
/*     */       {
/* 624 */         rIp[i][j] = (0xFF & Ip[i][j] >> 16);
/* 625 */         gIp[i][j] = (0xFF & Ip[i][j] >> 8);
/* 626 */         bIp[i][j] = (0xFF & Ip[i][j]);
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 635 */     int m = Ip.length;
/* 636 */     int n = Ip[0].length;
/*     */     int nn;
/*     */     int mm;
/*     */     int startX;
/*     */     int startY;
/*     */     int endX;
              int endY;
/* 637 */     if (quickInpaint.booleanValue())
/*     */     {
/* 639 */       startX = Math.max(0, this.pixelPosX - n / 2 - this.continuousRow - 25);
/* 640 */       startY = Math.max(0, this.pixelPosY - m / 2 - this.continuousCol - 15);
/* 641 */       endX = Math.min(this.pixelmap[0].length - 1, this.pixelPosX + n / 2 + this.continuousRow + 25);
/* 642 */       endY = Math.min(this.pixelmap.length - 1, this.pixelPosY + m / 2 + this.continuousCol + 15);
/* 643 */       mm = endY - startY + 1;
/* 644 */       nn = endX - startX + 1;
/*     */     }
/*     */     else
/*     */     {
/* 646 */       mm = this.pixelmap.length;
/* 647 */       nn = this.pixelmap[0].length;
/* 648 */       startX = 0;
/* 649 */       startY = 0;
/* 650 */       endX = endY = 0;
/*     */     }
/* 653 */     double patchErr = 0.0D;double err = 0.0D;double bestErr = 1.0E+020D;double bestPatchErr1 = 1.0E+020D;
/* 654 */     int[] best = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
/* 655 */     Boolean skipPatchFlag = Boolean.valueOf(false);
/*     */     
/*     */ 
/* 658 */     int N = startX + nn - n + 1;int M = startY + mm - m + 1;
/* 659 */     for (int j = startX; j < N; j++)
/*     */     {
/* 660 */       int J = j + n - 1;
/* 661 */       for (int i = startY; i < M; i++)
/*     */       {
/* 662 */         int I = i + m - 1;
/*     */         
/* 664 */         skipPatchFlag = Boolean.valueOf(false);
/*     */         
/* 666 */         double meanR = 0.0D;
/* 667 */         double meanG = 0.0D;
/* 668 */         double meanB = 0.0D;
/*     */         
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 674 */         int jj = j;
/* 674 */         for (int jj2 = 0; jj <= J; jj2++)
/*     */         {
/* 675 */           int ii = i;
/* 675 */           for (int ii2 = 0; ii <= I; ii2++)
/*     */           {
/* 680 */             if (sourceRegion[ii][jj] != 1)
/*     */             {
/* 681 */               skipPatchFlag = Boolean.valueOf(true);
/* 682 */               break;
/*     */             }
/* 684 */             if (toFill[ii2][jj2] == 0.0D)
/*     */             {
/* 685 */               int rImage = 0xFF & this.pixelmap[ii][jj] >> 16;
/* 686 */               int gImage = 0xFF & this.pixelmap[ii][jj] >> 8;
/* 687 */               int bImage = 0xFF & this.pixelmap[ii][jj];
/*     */               
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 692 */               err = rImage - rIp[ii2][jj2];patchErr += err * err;
/* 693 */               err = gImage - gIp[ii2][jj2];patchErr += err * err;
/* 694 */               err = bImage - bIp[ii2][jj2];patchErr += err * err;
/*     */               
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 698 */               meanR += rImage;
/* 699 */               meanG += gImage;
/* 700 */               meanB += bImage;
/*     */             }
/* 675 */             ii++;
/*     */           }
/* 703 */           if (skipPatchFlag.booleanValue()) {
/*     */             break;
/*     */           }
/* 674 */           jj++;
/*     */         }
/* 711 */         if ((!skipPatchFlag.booleanValue()) && (patchErr < bestErr))
/*     */         {
/* 712 */           bestErr = patchErr;
/* 713 */           best[0] = i;best[1] = I;
/* 714 */           best[2] = j;best[3] = J;
/*     */           
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 719 */           double patchErr1 = 0.0D;
/* 720 */           jj = j;
/* 720 */           for (int jj2 = 0; jj <= J; jj2++)
/*     */           {
/* 721 */             int ii = i;
/* 721 */             for (int ii2 = 0; ii <= I; ii2++)
/*     */             {
/* 722 */               if (toFill[ii2][jj2] == 1.0D)
/*     */               {
/* 723 */                 int rImage = 0xFF & this.pixelmap[ii][jj] >> 16;
/* 724 */                 int gImage = 0xFF & this.pixelmap[ii][jj] >> 8;
/* 725 */                 int bImage = 0xFF & this.pixelmap[ii][jj];
/*     */                 
/* 727 */                 err = rImage - meanR;patchErr1 += err * err;
/* 728 */                 err = gImage - meanG;patchErr1 += err * err;
/* 729 */                 err = bImage - meanB;patchErr1 += err * err;
/*     */               }
/* 721 */               ii++;
/*     */             }
/* 720 */             jj++;
/*     */           }
/* 733 */           bestPatchErr1 = patchErr1;
/*     */         }
/* 734 */         else if ((!skipPatchFlag.booleanValue()) && (patchErr == bestErr))
/*     */         {
/* 740 */           double patchErr1 = 0.0D;
/* 741 */           jj = j;
/* 741 */           for (int jj2 = 0; jj <= J; jj2++)
/*     */           {
/* 742 */             int ii = i;
/* 742 */             for (int ii2 = 0; ii <= I; ii2++)
/*     */             {
/* 743 */               if (toFill[ii2][jj2] == 1.0D)
/*     */               {
/* 744 */                 int rImage = 0xFF & this.pixelmap[ii][jj] >> 16;
/* 745 */                 int gImage = 0xFF & this.pixelmap[ii][jj] >> 8;
/* 746 */                 int bImage = 0xFF & this.pixelmap[ii][jj];
/*     */                 
/* 748 */                 err = rImage - meanR;patchErr1 += err * err;
/* 749 */                 err = gImage - meanG;patchErr1 += err * err;
/* 750 */                 err = bImage - meanB;patchErr1 += err * err;
/*     */               }
/* 742 */               ii++;
/*     */             }
/* 741 */             jj++;
/*     */           }
/* 758 */           if (bestPatchErr1 > patchErr1)
/*     */           {
/* 759 */             best[0] = i;best[1] = I;
/* 760 */             best[2] = j;best[3] = J;
/* 761 */             bestPatchErr1 = patchErr1;
/*     */           }
/*     */         }
/* 765 */         patchErr = 0.0D;
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 769 */     if ((best[0] == 0) && (best[1] == 0) && (best[2] == 0) && (best[3] == 0)) {
/* 770 */       return bestExemplar(Hp, toFill, sourceRegion, Boolean.valueOf(false));
/*     */     }
/* 772 */     return best;
/*     */   }
/*     */ }
```

Comment: *"Only one error still exists which is in the Calculategradient method and even in the GradientCalculator datatype gc in the beginning."* ... and that error would be?

Comment: Cannot resolve method CalculateGradient(int[][] int int) and cannot resolve symbol gradientX and gradientY

Comment: So you have declared a `GradientCalculator` object, however I see no `import some.package.GradientCalculator;` or a `private class GradientCalculator { ... }` in your code. So how does java know what a `GradientCalculator` is?

Comment: yeah I am using the statement "import inpaintutils.GradientCalculator;" but this too shows error and gets reddened in the android studio. So it doesnt recognise this. What shud be the correct import for this!

Comment: have u got solution?